# Unable to open Extension Development Host for TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to go through the first vs code extension tutorial, but I am unable to open the extension development host. Hitting F5 does nothing, and clicking on the start button in the debug sidebar doesn't seem to do anything either.

I have generated my project using `yo code` and picked the TypeScript option.

I have experimented with picking the JavaScript option and that seems to work fine.

`launch.json` looks like:

```
// A launch configuration that compiles the extension and then opens it inside a new window
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: watch"
        },
        {
            "name": "Extension Tests",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}",
                "--extensionTestsPath=${workspaceFolder}/out/test"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/test/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: watch"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Show `launch.json` file

Comment: Hi @RitwickDey I have updated the question to add my `launch.json` - I have not edited this though, it is just whatever was auto-generated

Comment: When you&#39;re hitting `F5` check output window &amp; console of vscode (help =&gt; toggle developer window)... is everything fine?

Comment: I have the same issue. Get `Extension host with pid 64350 exited with code: 0, signal: null.` in my Main log output window